# Facing problem while creating OnetoMany with JoinColumn in Hibernate while working with CASCADE

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to save data in WorkItem Table using a RestController with the below JSON:

> ```
> {
>     "wrkitmid": "123",
>     "linkingApplRef": [
>         {
>             "linkingApplRefid": "1",
>             "documentPage": [
>                 {
>                     "docpageid": 123
>                 }
>             ]
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

But I am getting this error

> Unable to find com.example.demo.LinkingApplRef with id 1

Edit:

As per Suggestion of Claudiu I tried with linkingApplRef in JSON which was present in DB & it executed successfully. But when I applied CASCADE in WorkItem Entity  :

```
@OneToMany(CASCADE) 
@JoinColumn(name = "WRK_ITM_ID") 
private List<LinkingApplRef> linkingApplRef;
```

& CASCADE in LinkingApplRef

```
@OneToMany(CASCADE) 
@JoinColumn(name = "LINK_APP_REF_ID") 
private List<DocumentPage> documentPage;
```

with the same JSON (with linkingApplRef with ID 1) it worked seamlessly without fail

Restcontroller is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveWorkItem", method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String savebiWorkItem (@RequestBody WorkItem w1) {
    System.out.println(w1);
    for (LinkingApplRef linkingApplRef : w1.getLinkingApplRef()) {
       linkingApplRef.setWorkItem(w1.getWrkitmid());
          for ( DocumentPage documentPage : linkingApplRef.getDocumentPage()) {
    documentPage.setLinkingApplRefid(linkingApplRef.getLinkingApplRefid());
            documentPage.setWorkItem(w1.getWrkitmid());
        }
   }
    try {
        workItemRepository.save(w1);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(w1);
    return "success";
}
```

WorkItem Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="WRK_ITM", schema="cf_2583f365_c3c6_499a_a60d_138e7e7023eb")
public class WorkItem {

@Id
@Column(name = "WRK_ITM_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int wrkitmid;

@OneToMany()
@JoinColumn(name = "WRK_ITM_ID")
private List<LinkingApplRef> linkingApplRef;

public WorkItem() {
    super();
}

public int getWrkitmid() {
    return wrkitmid;
}

public void setWrkitmid(int wrkitmid) {
    this.wrkitmid = wrkitmid;
}

public List<LinkingApplRef> getLinkingApplRef() {
    return linkingApplRef;
}

public void setLinkingApplRef(List<LinkingApplRef> linkingApplRef) {
    this.linkingApplRef = linkingApplRef;
}
```

Link app ref entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="LINK_APP_REF", schema="cf_2583f365_c3c6_499a_a60d_138e7e7023eb")
public class LinkingApplRef {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "LINK_APP_REF_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int linkingApplRefid;

    @Column(name = "WRK_ITM_ID")
    private int workItem;

    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn(name = "LINK_APP_REF_ID")
    private List<DocumentPage> documentPage;

    public LinkingApplRef() {
        super();
    }

    public int getLinkingApplRefid() {
        return linkingApplRefid;
    }

    public void setLinkingApplRefid(int linkingApplRefid) {
        this.linkingApplRefid = linkingApplRefid;
    }

    public int getWorkItem() {
        return workItem;
    }

    public void setWorkItem(int workItem) {
        this.workItem = workItem;
    }

    public List<DocumentPage> getDocumentPage() {
        return documentPage;
    }

    public void setDocumentPage(List<DocumentPage> documentPage) {
        this.documentPage = documentPage;
    }

    }
```

Document Page Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DOC_PAGE", schema="cf_2583f365_c3c6_499a_a60d_138e7e7023eb")
public class DocumentPage {

@Id
@Column(name = "DOC_PAGE_ID")

private int docpageid;


@Column(name = "WRK_ITM_ID")
private int workItemid;

@Column(name = "LINK_APP_REF_ID")
private int linkingApplRefid;


public DocumentPage() {
    super();
}


public int getDocpageid() {
    return docpageid;
}


public void setDocpageid(int docpageid) {
    this.docpageid = docpageid;

}

public int getWorkItem() {
    return workItemid;
}


public void setWorkItem(int workItem) {
    this.workItemid = workItem;
}


public int getLinkingApplRefid() {
    return linkingApplRefid;
}


public void setLinkingApplRefid(int linkingApplRefid) {
    this.linkingApplRefid = linkingApplRefid;
}
}
```

Stacktrace shows the below Error:

> ```
>     select
>         workitem0_.WRK_ITM_ID as WRK_ITM_1_5_0_ 
>     from
>         WRK_ITM workitem0_ 
>     where
>         workitem0_.WRK_ITM_ID=?
> ```

```
2019-02-04 00:49:46.845 TRACE 6232 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [123]
```

> ```
> 2019-02-04 00:49:46.924 DEBUG 6232 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
>     insert 
>     into
>         WRK_ITM
>
>     values
>         ( )
> 2019-02-04 00:49:46.936 DEBUG 6232 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
>     select
>         linkingapp0_.LINK_APP_REF_ID as LINK_APP1_1_0_,
>         linkingapp0_.WRK_ITM_ID as WRK_ITM_2_1_0_ 
>     from
>         LINK_APP_REF linkingapp0_ 
>     where
>         linkingapp0_.LINK_APP_REF_ID=?
> 2019-02-04 00:49:46.936 TRACE 6232 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as
> ```
>
> [INTEGER] - [1]

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com.example.demo.LinkingApplRef with id 1; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.example.demo.LinkingApplRef with id 1
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:507)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.demo.StudentsController.savebiWorkItem(StudentsController.java:133)
    at com.example.demo.StudentsController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3d32846e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:685)
    at com.example.demo.StudentsController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$13749923.savebiWorkItem(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.example.demo.LinkingApplRef with id 1
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1239)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1122)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:672)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:457)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:544)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replaceAssociations(TypeHelper.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:420)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:883)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:869)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.merge(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:304)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:493)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 68 more
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I see:
   "@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int linkingApplRefid;
   "
2. This means the value is generated by the DB, so you don't need to pass some id when you POST the request for create (insert) scenario. Having this configuration the id is passed only when updating some entity. From your SQL logs it seems the wrkitm is inserted and afterwards a read is executed for the linkingApplRef with ID 1, which does not exist in DB.

Comment: I got your point , I tried with linkingApplRef in JSON which was present in DB & it executed successfully. But when I applied CASCADE in WorkItem Entity & LinkingApplRef :                       
@OneToMany(CASCADE)
@JoinColumn(name = "WRK_ITM_ID")
private List<LinkingApplRef> linkingApplRef;                                                          @OneToMany(CASCADE)
@JoinColumn(name = "LINK_APP_REF_ID")
private List<DocumentPage> documentPage;                                                        
with the same JSON (with linkingApplRef with ID 1) it worked seamlessly without fail

Comment: Think i could work with Cascade because the persist event is cascaded, which means if the parent is persisted then also the children are persisted. I would suggest to revise the update case, in update case you should find first the entity based on Id, do the changes and afterwards call save. Please check here for more details: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-crud-repository-save